# Angular2 typescript - variable inside forloops

Tags: typescript, angular2-template

I need to use a variable inside a for loop from parent for loop:

I have a code like below:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
   <td *ngFor="let cols of columns">{{item.cols}}</td>   
   <td>{{item.receivedon}}</td>  
</tr>
```

{{item.cols}} should evaluate to something like item.userid and display its value e.g. administrator.

But currently its giving blank. I am sure this is incorrect syntax to add this logic. How to achieve this in Type script.

UPDATE:
Values for items an columns:

```
     items = [{"userid":'admin', receivedon:'26/6/2017','logged':'1'},
             {"userid":'user2', receivedon:'22/6/2017','logged':'0'}]
     columns = ['userid','logged'];
```

Comment: Can you post the data (or structure) you have in `items`, please ?

Comment: Just like in JavaScript/TypeScript: `item[cols]`

Comment: this works! Thanks.